# Use a Prop in Vue.js to change background color and pseudo element color

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there a way in vue using a prop to change background color which then would also change a psuedo element color? I would like to be able to call the component and then pass a css variable to the prop which would then update the background color of the CTA and the psuedo element. Not sure if this is even possible.

Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="callout" :style="{ backgroundColor: color }">
    <div class="callout__inner">
      <p>
        <slot name="callout-copy"></slot>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CalloutWithAngle",
  props: {
    color: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.callout {
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;
  max-width: 885px;
  margin: 0 auto 45px;

  background-color: BACKGROUND COLOR FROM PROP

  @media (max-width: $smallMax) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;

    display: block;

    width: 0;
    height: 0;

    content: "";
    transform: rotate(10deg);

    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid darken(BACKGROUND COLOR FROM PROP, 10%);
    border-left: 140px solid transparent;

    @media (max-width: $smallMax) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
.callout__inner {
  padding: 30px 40px;
  p {
    text-align: center;

    color: $white;

    font-weight: $robotoBold;

    @include fluid-type(font-size, $mobileMin, $mobileMax, 20px, 20px);
  }
}
</style>
```

Component Call:

```
  <CalloutWithAngle color="$pink"> <-- use variable here from css 
            <template slot="callout-copy">
             "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            </template>
          </CalloutWithAngle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only ways you can update a pseudo element's style from javascript is to:

- apply a css class. But you'd have to declare a class for each and every possible prop value.
- use css custom properties (aka css variables)

```html
<div class="callout" :style="`--element-color: ${colorProp}`">
...

<style>
  border-bottom: 25px solid var(--element-color);
</style>
```

- Or you could avoid using a pseudo element and use a real element instead. It will likely behave the same if it's positioned as absolute.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to change background color depending on props is to bind class to the element you want, e.g.

```
<div class="base-class" v-bind:class="{ 'conditional-class': isActive }"></div>
```

where `conditional-class` is your class, and `isActive` is the props name.
This will apply the class to the element always when `isActive` will be true.

You can also bind a CSS class (not SCSS) if you want, by creating a computed property like this

```
// data or props
color: '#fff'


//computed
bgColor() {
    return {
        '--bg-color': this.color
    };
},
```

then bind it to the element:

`<div :style="bgColor"></div>`

and finally, use that variable in your styles

`var(--bg-color);`

Comment: This computed property gives you the option to dynamically change CSS variable color, e.g.:

bgColor() {
    const color =  this.colorDark ? '#000' : '#FFF';

    return { '--bg-color': color };
}